# Vertically Center - jQuery

Tags: jquery, alignment

I have a bunch of images at random heights and widths that need to be vertically and horizontally centered.

For whatever reason it stopped working. Could anyone spare some help? I have no knowledge of jQuery (someone gave me the code).

[Image 1](http://christopherburton.net/lettering/h)

[Image 2](http://christopherburton.net/typography/nerdie-networks)

```
//jQuery by Juan Mendes
$(window).load(function(){
  var $img = $('img');

  $img.css({'display': 'block',
          'margin-left': '-' + ($img.width() / 2) + 'px',
          'margin-top': '-' + ($img.height() / 2) + 'px'});
});
```

Comment: Did you debug it? What values is your script trying to set margin to?

Comment: All I did was remove the negative margin values for each image. I tried putting the jQuery script at the bottom as that is what I was told. After that, I tried wrapping the script in a document ready function. Nothing seemed to work.

Comment: @ChristopherBurton See my answer, you need to wrap it with the `onload` handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a breakpoint in center.js and that shows that your images have no width/height when you're calling `$img.css`

For you to guarantee that your script runs after images have been loaded, you have to wrap it with an onload handler

```
$(window).load(function(){
  var $img = $('img');

  $img.css({'display': 'block',
          'margin-left': '-' + ($img.width() / 2) + 'px',
          'margin-top': '-' + ($img.height() / 2) + 'px'});
});
```

Comment: THANKS! Is there any way to get the images from jumping to center?

Comment: Yes, hide the images with CSS. The script above will make them display again.